# When does the MethodHandle of an Exception change?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memory-management, reflection

I'm trying to see if I can group exceptions together in some legacy code. I have a `Logger` class that accepts the exception and log's it. Ideally I want some kind of unique identifier (regardless of the text) of where an exception was thrown.

I stumbled upon the `Exception.TargetSite.MethodHandle`. This appeared to be a integer that I could use to do just what I wanted. In debug I fired an exception multiple times and noticed that the values appeared static, great!

[image]

So I moved the exception to confirm that it'd alter if the exception was different, the value changed, also great!

I put the exception back to where is was originally and tested again, expecting the original integer value to be returned, but it wasn't, it returned a totally different value. :(

It appears that the values changes everytime I recompile the source.

This leads me to my question. The docs on `MethodHandle` [are not great](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.methodhandle(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets a handle to the internal metadata representation of a method.

Thanks Microsoft very informative. I'm presuming that the `MethodHandle` is some kind of address in memory for the method? Though I'm not sure. Can anyone explain when and why this value changes? Is it stamped in the assembly or is it a memory address on the stack or heap? Will it change when the process recycles?

Comment: Why not just hash the stack trace?

Comment: This is interesting! I used to uniquely identify exceptions by their stacktrace. I hope we could get some answers

Comment: I did consider this @Lloyd , but this seemed to be simple identifier that would require no extra processing.

Comment: @Liam It's safer than using something like a handle, which will have a transient value, especially considering we don't know what it does internally, it could be a memory pointer etc.

Comment: I guess the `MethodHandle` is valid inside a method.The value changes every time I execute my console application.`MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().MethodHandle` and `ex.TargetSite.MethodHandle` has the same value.

Comment: You probably should format `TargetSite` as a string (assembly name, type name, member name). Wouldn't that work? That's a lot more stable than any magic assembly metadata number.

Answer (score 2):

The value you see is a pointer to a `MethodDesc` structure in the CLR, which is not guaranteed to keep the same value. If you need to identify a method in a module, you can use its `MetadataToken`, but it may change if you recompile the module.